# Missing Analysis Services in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2017, ssas

I have installed VS 2017 Pro and also SQL Server Data Tools.
But when I try to create a new Project, the BI-Template is missing (SSAS, SSIS and SSRS).
Is there something additional to install or how can I fix this?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Visual Studio is already installed, you can [edit the list of workloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) to include SSDT:

[Download SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.8)](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2014060)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you will find yourself doing this on a weekly basis, as SSAS template and SSRS template constantly disappear... standard MS product, half written, and buggy as anything